# Add days to date in pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have a data frame that contains 2 columns, one is Date and other is float number.
I would like to add those 2 to get the following:

```
   Index           Date           Days           NewDate
     0           20-04-2016        5           25-04-2016
     1           16-03-2015       3.7          20-03-2015
```

As you can see if there is decimal it is converted as int as 3.1--> 4 (days).
I have some weird questions so I appreciate any help.
Thank you !

Comment: Convert days into timedelta frama and then do operation between Date and Days . Please see the documentation on operations at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html they have exactly this example case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, ensure that the `Date` column is a datetime object:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then, we can convert the `Days` column to int by ceiling it and the converting it to a pandas Timedelta:

```
temp = df['Days'].apply(np.ceil).apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x, unit='D'))
```

Datetime objects and timedeltas can be added:

```
df['NewDate'] = df['Date'] + temp
```

Comment: How would one add on `Days` to _todays date_ and create a `NewDate`?

Comment: Please open a new question. This is not directly related to the original question.

Comment: I posted a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849390/how-to-create-a-new-column-of-dates-by-adding-a-corresponding-column-of-days-to)

Answer (score 16):

You can convert the Days column to `timedelta` and add it to `Date` column:

```
import pandas as pd

df['NewDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) + pd.to_timedelta(pd.np.ceil(df.Days), unit="D")
df
```

[image]

Comment: How would one create `NewDate` by adding `Days` to today's date? ie `df['NewDate'] = ??date_of_today??  + pd.to_timedelta(pd.np.ceil(df.Days), unit="D")`

Comment: cannot add DatetimeIndex and DatetimeIndex

Comment: Best one, for now on, use directly numpy and not from pandas 
pd.np.ceil(df.Days) --> np.ceil(df.Days)

Comment: Can it be done with business days?  unit="B" doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

using `combine` for two columns calculations and `pd.DateOffset` for adding `days`

```
df['NewDate'] = df['Date'].combine(df['Days'], lambda x,y: x + pd.DateOffset(days=int(np.ceil(y))))
```

output:

```
        Date  Days    NewDate
0 2016-04-20   5.0 2016-04-25
1 2016-03-16   3.7 2016-03-20
```