# How to create a new column of dates by adding a corresponding column of days to today's date using PANDAS

Tags: pandas, datetime

The final column of my dataframe `df` looks like:

```
    ...   Days till Service
0   ...                   0
1   ...                  28
2   ...                   7
3   ...                  54
4   ...                   0
5   ...                   6
6   ...                  28
7   ...                   0
8   ...                  16
9   ...                 200
```

**Question:**

I want to create a new column named `Predicted Service Date`, where I can add the `Days till Service` on to today's date. How can I do this?

**Ideal Output:**

If today's date is `16/04/2018`, then the `df` should look as the following:

```
    ...   Days till Service   Predicted Service Date
0   ...                   0               16/04/2018
1   ...                  28               14/05/2018
2   ...                   7               23/04/2018
3   ...                  54               09/06/2018
4   ...                   0               16/04/2018
5   ...                   6               22/04/2018
6   ...                 365               16/04/2019
7   ...                   0               16/04/2018
8   ...                  16               02/05/2018
9   ...                 200               02/11/2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), you can convert `df['Days till Service']` to timedeltas, then add them to today's date:

```
df['Predicted Service Date'] = \
    pd.to_datetime('today') + pd.to_timedelta(df['Days till Service'], unit='D')
```

Comment: typo - _timedetas_ should be timedeltas

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is define a date offset and then add it to a DateTime. Pandas accept `datetime()` and `Timestamp` as well so feel free to use either.

You can define `offsets` using `Day`, start by converting your offset series into `Day` offset class and then add the DateTime of whatever starting point to it.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day
from datetime import datetime
df['Predicted Service Date'] = df['Days till Service'].apply(Day) + datetime(2018, 4, 17) #Or What everdate you would like
```

Comment: Explain your answer so that others can benefit from it in future.

Comment: I explained it briefly, feel free to edit or feedback :)